# Requisitos funcionais, requisitos não funcionais e requisitos de domínio, quais são as diferenças entre eles?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Requisitos funcionais no meu entendimento são aqueles que descrevem o que o sistema irar fazer, ou seja, as principais funcionalidades de um sistema (não sei se é a melhor definição).

Veja o exemplo de requisitos funcionais:

> Cadastrar Cliente;
>   Cadastrar Fornecedor;
>   Efetuar uma venda;

Porem, estou confuso em relação as diferenças dos *requisitos funcionais* em comparação com ***requisitos não funcionais*** e ***requisitos de domínio***.

Qual é a finalidade deles e o que eles são?

*Obs: Se puderem explicar mostrando exemplos em que mostra a aplicação deles.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

São termos que fazem parte do processo de [Engenharia de Requisitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_requisitos).

Como existe muita literatura técnica disponível (ver *links* no final) a respeito, esta resposta é um exemplo "prático" (**fictício e simplificado**):

---

### Cenário

A empresa vai desenvolver um software para uma [corretora de valores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corretora_de_valores) e, abaixo, segue um trecho do diálogo entre **o analista** responsável pelo levantamento de requisitos e o cliente (**gerente**).

---

### Entrevista

`. . .`

**Gerente -** Preciso também, que o sistema me forneça um relatório *realtime* de todas as operações
feitas por cliente. As de maior valor são as mais importantes para mim, pois se for necessário tomar
alguma providência eu tenho que agir bem rápido.

**Analista -** Quais informações esse relatório precisa ter?

**Gerente -** Ora...o básico, valor da operação, se a origem foi a mesa ou [home broker](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Broker), ...  e o saldo de cada cliente, já descontando
emolumentos, corretagem...essas taxas. Mas se  for uma [venda descoberta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venda_a_descoberto), principalmente [day trade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_trading), eu preciso que isso apareça em vermelho
 no sistema porque pode ser um problema.

**Analista -** Day Trade?

**Gerente -** É! Day trade, comprou e vendeu no mesmo dia....preciso saber disso na hora!

**Analista -** E se em algum momento o sistema sistema fica indisponível?

**Gerente -** Esse sistema não pode ficar indisponível!!

`. . .`

---

A partir do diálogo acima, é possível perceber (exemplo) os seguintes **requisitos** (além da importância da Engenharia de Requisitos):

---

### [Requisito Funcional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requisito_funcional)

O sistema deve gerar um relatório com as informações:

- valor_da_operação
- ação (`XYZ`, neste exemplo)
- day_trade `(data da compra de XYZ na carteira do cliente == data da venda dessas ações)`
- descoberta `( (número de XYZ na carteira do cliente - número de XYZ vendidas) < 0 )`
- origem da operação
- saldo devedor do cliente

Ordenar por: day_trade, descoberta, valor_da_operação (decrescente)

---

### [Requisitos não-funcionais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requisito_n%C3%A3o-funcional)

Há várias subdivisões aqui, mas de forma simples:

***Requisitos de Usabilidade:***

- *"apareça em vermelho"*
- *"venda descoberta, principalmente day trade"*

A cor de fundo das linhas do relatório deve ser VERMELHA, para a seguinte condição:

`(day_trade = Verdadeiro) OU (descoberta = Verdadeiro)`

***Requisitos de eficiência:***
***Requisitos de confiabilidade:***
***Requisitos de entrega:***

- *"realtime"*
- *"preciso saber disso na hora"*
- *"Esse sistema não pode ficar indisponível"*

O sistem deve possuir um sistema de rendundância de conexão

O sistema deve possuir um sistema de redundância elétrica

O sistema deve possuir redundância física

para mais informações: [FUNDAMENTOS DE TOLERÂNCIA A FALHAS](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~pmdusso/works/Fundamentos_Tolerancia_Falhas.htm)

---

### [Requisitos de Domínio](http://www.semeru.com.br/blog/category/requisitos-de-dominio/)

- *"emolumentos, corretagem"*

> Os requisitos de domínio são derivados do domínio da aplicação do sistema que podem ser novos requisitos funcionais em si, podem restringir os requisitos funcionais existentes ou estabelecer como devem ser executados cálculos específicos.

O domínio da aplicação, neste exemplo, é "uma corretora de valores operando no mercado financeiro".

Um exemplo de requisito de domínio: é necessário consultar a legislação (do domínio da aplicação, ex: [CVM](http://www.cvm.gov.br/legislacao/)) para efetuar corretamente
os cálculos das taxas.

Essa legislação pode, inclusive, gerar novos requisitos funcionais (não previstos pelo cliente) ou restringir requisitos já solicitados.

Links sobre o assunto:

[Artigo Engenharia de Software - Introdução à Engenharia de Requisitos](http://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-engenharia-de-software-introducao-a-engenharia-de-requisitos/8034)

[Engenharia de requisitos: processos e técnicas no contexto organizacional](http://www.batebyte.pr.gov.br/modules/conteudo/conteudo.php?conteudo=601)

Google: [engenharia de requisitos pdf](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=engenharia+de+requisitos+pdf)

Google: [requisitos funcionais não funcionais e de domínio pdf](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=requisitos+funcionais+n%C3%A3o+funcionais+e+de+dom%C3%ADnio+pdf)

Comment: Realmente, esses conceitos da engenharia de requisitos causa muita confusão, valeu pela resposta, esclareceu varias duvidas minha.